# Does the inertia change of the uniformly accelerated charge because of the recoil force?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Does a charge that is uniformly accelerated emit radiation? Is there a recoil force because of that?

There is the Abraham-Lorentz force which is given by:
$$\mathbf{F}_\mathrm{rad} = \frac{\mu_0 q^2}{6 \pi c} \mathbf{\dot{a}} $$
But for a uniform accelerated charge $\mathbf{\dot{a}} = \vec{0} $ so $\mathbf{F}_\mathrm{rad}= \vec{0}$

Does the inertia change of the uniformly accelerated charge?

Answer (score 2):

> Does a charge that is uniformly accelerated emit radiation?

Yes. This follows from Maxwell's equations and condition of retarded fields; accelerated charge does have radiation-like electric field. Details about reaction force are not relevant.

> Is there a recoil force because of that?

It depends on which variant of the theory we use.

For spatially extended charges, there is backreaction due to interaction between different parts of the charge. One component of this backreaction is proportional to acceleration, and thus modifies effective mass. The other component is the Lorentz-Abraham-Dirac force (LAD force). In case acceleration is constant, this is zero, but there may be other terms which become important then, and total backreaction may still be non-zero. For extended charge, backreaction of the LAD is almost certain to exist, since without backreaction forces, it would be hard to explain antenna energy losses or particle bunch radiation losses in accelerators.

For point charges, the situation is different. Poynting's expressions can't be interpreted in energy terms (due to divergencies and infinities). There are alternatives free of divergences like Frenkel's theory or the Feynman-Wheeler theory, where point charge does not act on itself. Consequently, there is no backreaction on point charge that is accelerating and radiating.

Whether this second kind of theory (based on assumption of no self-interaction of point charges) is true for real particles like electrons is not clear, because the hypothetical radiation reaction force on single electron (as predicted from the LAD formula) is so small it is experimentally indistinguishable from zero.

Comment: A problem with these old fashioned alternatives is that a charge orbiting an opposite charge of far larger mass won't spiral inwards, yet still radiates. L&L's approach in their 1950 classical fields book via the Lagrangian is far better; and advanced later on by Coleman emphasizing the self-effect of the radiation field is the correct approach IMO. But credit should be given to Dirac for noting that the radiation field is the difference between the advanced and retarded fields.

Comment: "But credit should be given to Dirac for noting that the radiation field is the difference between the advanced and retarded fields."

What does this mean exactly?

Comment: @LarryHarson > *A problem with these old fashioned alternatives is that a charge orbiting an opposite charge of far larger mass won't spiral inwards, yet still radiates.* -- Why is that a problem? What is the L&L approach here, where in their book? What do you mean by "correct approach", in what sense? I don't agree on the difference between the advanced and retarded fields. That was just Dirac's working definition of "radiation" in that paper. There is infinity of different definitions, solutions of the homogeneous equations. Dirac's is just one of them.